# Emoticons doesn't work with multiple emoji in (Saferi and Chrome browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I am trying to make a emoticon using jquery. But i have a problem with multiple emoji. I have created this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nxhmz0nv/) from jsfiddle.net .

The jquery code is working fine with if user write different multiple emoji but if user write two or more smile like :):):):) then jquery code showing just first emoji other emoji will not showing. Anyone can help me here ?

JS

```
jQuery.fn.emoticons = function(icon_folder) {
    /* emoticons is the folder where the emoticons are stored*/
    var icon_folder = icon_folder || "emoticons";
    //var settings = jQuery.extend({emoticons: "emoticons"}, options);
    /* keys are the emoticons
     * values are the ways of writing the emoticon
     *
     * for each emoticons should be an image with filename
     * 'face-emoticon.png'
     * so for example, if we want to add a cow emoticon
     * we add "cow" : Array("(C)") to emotes
     * and an image called 'face-cow.png' under the emoticons folder   
     */
    var emotes = {"smile": Array(":-)",":)","=]","=)"),
                  "sad": Array(":-(","=(",":[",":&lt;"),
                  "wink": Array(";-)",";)",";]","*)"),
                  "grin": Array(":D","=D","XD","BD","8D","xD"),
                  "surprise": Array(":O","=O",":-O","=-O"),
                  "devilish": Array("(6)"),
                  "angel": Array("(A)"),
                  "crying": Array(":'(",":'-("),
                  "plain": Array(":|"),
                  "smile-big": Array(":o)"),
                  "glasses": Array("8)","8-)"),
                  "kiss": Array("(K)",":-*"),
                  "monkey": Array("(M)")};

    /* Replaces all ocurrences of emoticons in the given html with images
     */
    function emoticons(html){
        for(var emoticon in emotes){
            for(var i = 0; i < emotes[emoticon].length; i++){
                /* css class of images is emoticonimg for styling them*/
                html = html.replace(emotes[emoticon][i],"<img src=\"http://www.oobenn.com/"+icon_folder+"/face-"+emoticon+".png\" class=\"emoticonimg\" alt=\""+emotes[emoticon][i]+"\"/>","g");
            }
        }
        return html;
    }
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).html(emoticons($(this).html()));
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".posted").emoticons();
});
```

Comment: Why is your issue? in your example, is work fine, all emoji appears yet :):):):):)

Comment: @P.Frank Did you see the red text in demo page ? The problem is on there.

Comment: yes and i see all emoji below the red text

Comment: @P.Frank Can you show me screenshot. Because i have an error on there ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jsQuT.png

Comment: @P.Frank please look at this screenshot [CLICK](https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/12310079_209983382668162_2154144656596689137_o.jpg)

Comment: ok, you use Chrome and effectively dont work i look now

Comment: Yes, the flags in `replace` are not working in Chrome (deprecated), see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you will need regular expressions as the flags (your `,"g"`) in `replace` are deprecated and will not work on every browser ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)).

So you need to create your regexp with your smiley code:

```
var re = new RegExp(emotes[emoticon][i], 'g');
```

But as your smiley codes has special characters, you need to escape them. To do that, I took a piece of code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/3493954):

```
function escape(smiley){
  return smiley.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

Finaly, you can use `replace` to replace all your smileys, even when there is several times the same smiley:

```
var escaped = escape(emotes[emoticon][i]);
var re = new RegExp(escaped, 'g');
html = html.replace(re,"<img src=\"http://www.oobenn.com/"+icon_folder+"/face-"+emoticon+".png\" class=\"emoticonimg\" alt=\""+emotes[emoticon][i]+"\"/>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jh8fs9dp/)**

Comment: Thanks for your best answer. It is very good description for me and i understood what i am missing in the code. Thank you so much again.